# clear content in certain div if domain contain certain string

Tags: jquery

I have this code but it is not working, any help please~

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
if(domain.indexOf('extraordinaire') >= 0) {
    $('.navigation-v').empty(); // clear value
}    
</script>
```

I would like to detect if the domain(the part befor .com) contains string "extraordinaire", then clear content inside the class element "navigation-v"
e.g.
www.xxxextraordinaire.com/index.php

Comment: is jquery library loaded?

Comment: `domain` => `ReferenceError: domain is not defined` you might want to use `location.href`?

Comment: Wrap the code inside $(document).ready and check if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.href.indexOf('extraordinaire') >= 0) {
        $('.navigation-v').empty(); // clear value
    }    
});
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ad9jA/)**